# google script can you use the IDE debugger to step through debug a called google script library

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, shared-libraries

I have a google doc script that executes a function in a google script library I created (Call - calls Lib1.lib1function() ). I'm wondering if I set a breakpoint in the IDE debugger in the google doc script where I'm making a call to a function in the library script and get the debugger to expose the execution of the library function. ie. keep tracking execution in the called library. Or is my only debugging technique in the script library, Logger.log() and writing info to the console?

The only other debugging solution I can think of is to copy the actual library script (Lib1) to a new Google Doc script file and test and execute the code there. Once I'm done creating and testing the code, I would then copy it back to the library script for other docs to use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot debug a library on another project. The optimal way to debug a library is to create another function in your library script that will call the library method or create unit tests.

Here I used QUnit to create unit test for my library method `sumArray`.

```
QUnit.helpers(this);
function sumArray(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
    if(isNaN(arr[i])){
      return "Non-numerical data detected";
    }else{
      sum = sum + arr[i];
    }       
  }
  return sum;
}

function testFunction(){
  testingSumArray();
}

function testingSumArray(){
  QUnit.test( "sumArray testing", function() {
      expect(2);
      equal( sumArray([1,2,3,4,5]), 15 , "Test for Array [1,2,3,4,5], Output is 15" );
      equal( sumArray([1,'a','b','c',4]), "Non-numerical data detected", "Test for Array [1,'a','b','c',4]: Output is Non-numerical data detected" );
   });
}

function doGet( e ) {
  QUnit.urlParams( e.parameter );
  QUnit.config({ title: "sumArray Unit tests" });
  QUnit.load( testFunction );
  return QUnit.getHtml();
};
```

**Output:**

[image]

To learn how to use QUnit in Apps Script, you can check the documentation [here](https://github.com/simula-innovation/qunit/tree/gas/gas).

Comment: I think you missed the point of the OP's question. The OP want's to know if he can use it to step through a function in a library.  I think his question suggest that he has some idea about what the debugger is and how to use it.

Comment: Yes, I want to know if you can step/debug into a function in a library. A library that I have full access to the source code.

Or what techniques, besides Logger.log() do people use to debug libraries. One solution I have is to copy the library code to a local script file. Debug it, then copy it back to the library and deploy a new version.

Comment: @Cooper - Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: It certainly is a pity not to be able to naturally debug project and libraries within. Unit test are good (and even recommended) but sometime you need the real environment for bugs to pop up....

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I am using the following workaround for google sheets in a library where most code if not all has to to do with the active Spreadsheet. To debug directly within the library code, I always use a wrapper function of getActiveSpreadsheet() to get the active sheet, so if it is null I return a default spreadsheet using its ID.

```
//update with your spreadsheet ID
const DEFAULT_SPREADSHEET_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"   

function getActiveSsheet(){
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  if (null == spreadSheet){
    spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DEFAULT_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  } 
  return spreadSheet
}
```